# Deriving coordinates from Application.Display or MxDocument.ActiveView in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, point

I've found two possible ways of converting a `MouseEventsArg`'s coordinates to the coordinates of the current map:

The first is taken from a snippet included with ArcObjects:

```
protected override IPoint OnMouseDown(ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool.MouseEventArgs arg)
{
    IPoint screenPt = new Point();
    screenPt.PutCoords(arg.X, arg.Y);

    IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
    mxdoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint((System.Int32)screenPt.X, (System.Int32)
}
```

The second was included in some code I've inherited:

```
protected override IPoint OnMouseDown(ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool.MouseEventArgs arg)
{
    IPoint pnt;
    IMxApplication app = ArcMap.Application as IMxApplication;
    IPoint pnt = app.Display.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

As far as I can tell, the first is drawing the transformation information from the `ActiveView` of an `MxDocument`, while the second takes it from the `Display` of the `ArcMap.Application`.

Is there ever a time when these two codes will return `Point`s with different XY coordinates?

Is one way safer than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good question Philip, I've always used the second method (note it should be `ToMapPoint(arg.x, arg.y)` as `e` doesn't appear in the code anywhere!).

In the first method you are casting an int to a double and then back to an int which *should* return exactly the same value...

The X and Y (and Z and M) properties of an IPoint are of type Double, the [ToMapPoint](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ToMapPoint_Method/001w000000tm000000/) expects arguments of type Int. The [MouseEventArgs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001v00000133000000) [X](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4e6k4k1) and [Y](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bxct58b) properties are of type Int... custom made for the 2nd method:

```
protected override IPoint OnMouseDown(ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool.MouseEventArgs arg)
{
    IPoint pnt;
    IMxApplication app = ArcMap.Application as IMxApplication;
    IPoint pnt = app.Display.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y);
}
```

So, I cannot see any benefit of converting to an IPoint and then back to an int; it could be considered dangerous to unnecessarily cast like this but probably isn't.

As a side note, a lighter weight object to store coordinates is an [IPnt](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000693000000) or [WKSPoint](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0042000002qw000000) - they both have X & Y (as double) but don't have many (if any) methods... can be handy to return these without being concerned about spatial reference etc..

Comment: That makes total sense. And even if casting up and back down again isn't dangerous, it is less efficient. Thanks for the IPnt tip; I need to convert coordinates into WGS1984, but when conversions aren't necessary, that'll definitely come in useful.